# Classification execution time - Orange

Tags: orange

Is there any way to find out execution time for classification algorithms in orange?

Comment: you mean during training or recall?

Comment: During training

Answer (score 2):

you can just use time library and give time counter like time save to variable and after classification take time now save to variable and subtract both and print the result you get the execution time